# How to find tweets from a specific date

Tags: twitter

I am following someone who has a lot of tweets. I want to look at their tweets from three months ago. On their twitter web page, if I scroll down, it keeps showing their older tweets, but using this method will take too long. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 4):

Try one of the solutions explained here [“How To Search Old Tweets Until Twitter Lets You Download Yours”](https://web.archive.org/web/20150415002518/http://blog.tweetsmarter.com/twitter-search/10-ways-and-20-features-for-searching-old-tweets/) at the Wayback Machine (archived 15 April 2015)

Some tools to help you search for old tweets:

- [TwimeMachine](http://www.twimemachine.com/)
- [SnapBird](http://snapbird.org/)
- [Topsy](http://topsy.com/advanced-search?q=twitter&window=d)
- [The Archivist](http://www.tweetarchivist.com/)
- [All My Tweets](http://www.allmytweets.net/)
- [Google Tweet Search](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=anyone%20recommend%E2%80%9D#q=site:twitter.com%20%22looking%20for%22%20OR%20%22anyone%20help%22%20OR%20%22%28would%20OR%20can%29%20you%20recommend%22%20OR%20%22anyone%20%28recommend%20OR%20know%29%22%20OR%20%22anyone%20recommend%22%20OR%20%22anyone%20recommend%22%20-RT&hl=en&tbo=1&prmdo=1&prmd=ivns&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1,qdr:d&sa=X&ei=VXIXTvz4Kafz0gGH6s2WBQ&ved=0CBQQpwUoAg&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=f6055f761472d156&biw=1434&bih=945)

Comment: Really impressed with Topsy. They had a clear filter to a single user, min date, max date, and sorted by newest/oldest to find the tweet I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Using third party applications are great for searching as I use Tweetdeck. Perhaps if you're searching for a specific tweet by that individual you are following, search by keywords, that is if you're searching for a certain tweet instead of all of that person's tweets.