# How to go on tweets from specific date or year without using third party app

Tags: twitter

There are two cases;

1. When I scroll https://twitter.com/home, it goes up to last 3-4 days.
2. I follow @xyz and scroll all tweets of @xyz, it also goes to last
   3-4 days.

In both cases, I want tweets from a specific data or year.

Please let me know, how to find tweets like this?

I found a link [How to find tweets from a specific date](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13847/how-to-find-tweets-from-a-specific-date)

The link says, use third party apps. 
Can it be done without using third party app?
TekQ

Answer (score 1):

You can do a Twitter search that will give you exactly what you're looking for. The structure of the search query is as follows:

```
from:username since:yyyy-mm-dd until:yyyy-mm-dd
```

So, for example, if you wish to see tweets by @CNN between the 1st and 2nd of December 2020, your search query would look like this:

```
from:CNN since:2020-12-01 until:2020-12-02
```

You can see the [results here...](https://twitter.com/search?q=from%3ACNN%20since%3A2020-12-01%20until%3A2020-12-02%20&src=typed_query&f=live)